# Xamarin.Essentials Screenshot not working on Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, screenshot, xamarin.essentials

I am following the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/screenshot to take a screenshot and save it to `MemoryStream` then use it as the image source to "imagetest" (on a button click. Below is my code for the `CaptureScreenshot()` function, and I am getting the below error when executing the button click on an Android 10 device. I am running the latest versions of Xamarin.Essentials and Xamarin.Forms.

Function:

```
        private async void CaptureScreenshot(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var screenshot = await Screenshot.CaptureAsync();
        var stream = await screenshot.OpenReadAsync();
        var array_image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
        imagetest.Source = array_image;
    }
```

Error:

> "System.TypeLoadException
> Message=Could not load type of field 'Order_Form_V1.CustomArrayConfiguration+d__3:5__2' (6) due to: Could not resolve type with token 01000029 from typeref (expected class 'Xamarin.Essentials.ScreenshotResult' in assembly 'Xamarin.Essentials, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null') assembly:Xamarin.Essentials, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null type:Xamarin.Essentials.ScreenshotResult member:(null)"

I appreciate any input I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a try with **cleaning** the solution and **removing** all bin and obj folders, then **rebulding** it to check whether it works.

Xamarin Forms: `5.0.0.1874`

Xamarin Essentials: `1.6.0`

Visual Studio : `16.8.4`

Comment: Wow - worked like a charm! Thank you so much :)

Comment: I am taking screenshot of my video app. It takes screenshot but does not capture video part. video part is black. anyone to help?